# How to move text from one Textblock to another Textblock using Drag and Drop in a Universal Windows Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I know how to set properties like CanDrag and AllowDrop and define DragOver method and Drop method.
I just don't know what to write inside the Drop method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to move text from one Textblock to another Textblock using Drag and Drop

We can define [`DragStarting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.dragstarting.aspx) event for the source `Textblock` and save the text of the source `Textblock` in [`DragStartingEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dragstartingeventargs.aspx)  for transfer during dragging. And accept the text when [drop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.drop.aspx) at target `Textblock`. Read the text from [`DragEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.drageventhandler.aspx) and set it to the target `Textblock`.

I wrote a simple sample here, move the text from `txtsource` to append to `txttarget`.

XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Padding="30">
    <Border BorderBrush="Azure" BorderThickness="2">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtsource" Text="I'm the first textblock" CanDrag="True" DragStarting="txtsource_DragStarting"  />
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="Azure" BorderThickness="2" Margin="20" AllowDrop="True" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="txttarget" Text="I'm the second textblock" Drop="txttarget_Drop"  Height="50" Width="400"  AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="txttarget_DragEnter"/>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
  private void txtsource_DragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
  {
      args.Data.SetText(txtsource.Text);
  }

  private async void txttarget_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
      bool hasText = e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text);
      e.AcceptedOperation = hasText ? DataPackageOperation.Copy : DataPackageOperation.None;
      if (hasText)
      {
          var text = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
          txttarget.Text +="\n"+ text;
      }
  }
  private void txttarget_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
      bool hasText = e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text);
      e.AcceptedOperation = hasText ? DataPackageOperation.Copy : DataPackageOperation.None;
      if (hasText)
      {
          e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "Drop here to insert text";
      }
  }
```

I use [`DragOver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.dragover.aspx) event to help define which area can be drop. More details please reference the scenario 2 of the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop).